A tooltip from an underlying activity overlaps the fragment which is at the top of stack
I have MainActivity with a tooltip attached to BottomNavigation. This tooptip in fact is a custom view with some elevation:
private fun initialize(attrs: AttributeSet? = null) {
    ...
    ViewCompat.setElevation(this, 2 * resources.displayMetrics.density)
    ...
}

BottomNavigation is a Compose view, from androidx.compose.material.
And then I want to open a new fragment, NewFragment, on the very top of the stack, with the help of Navigation Component (in fact it's redirection to another graph). This new fragment is opened, but it's overlapped by the tooltip.
I've tried to add elevation to the root ConstraintLayout of the layout of NewFragment:
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        android:elevation="128dp">

but no matter how big this elevation is (I've tried even 128dp), the tooltip overlaps the fragment anyway.
What else could be done here to resolve this issue?
